# How to show the parameters passed to jsreport in the report

Tags: jsreport

I send a few input field values as parameters to jsreport to show a report based on the the parameters. How do I show the parameters that are passed in the report that is generated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create helper function

```
function toJSON(data) {
  return JSON.stringify(data);
}
```

and then the print the whole serialized input data into the report (using handlebars for example)

```
<span>{{{toJSON this}}}</span>
```